# Функция split для выборки подстроки из строки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как использовать `split` для разбиения строки с сохранением разделителя?

Сейчас использую так:

```
var scope = $('#id'); //например, имеет значение 'тек'
var str = 'какой-то текст на киррилице';
var highligth = str.split($(scope).val()); // ???
console.log(highligth); // нужно получить массив ['какой-то ','тек','ст на киррилице']
```

Т.е. есть объект `scope`, который содержит пользовательский ввод, и строка , которую надо разбить по введенному пользователем значению.

В таком варианте переменная `highligth` равна `['какой-то ','ст на киррилице']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) может принимать в качестве параметра регулярное выражение.
Для вашего примера подходит выражение с группировкой

```js
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify('какой-то текст на киррилице'.split(/(тек)/));
```

**UPDATE** с [динамическим регулярным выражением](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
var separator = 'тек';
var r = new RegExp('('+separator+')');
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify('какой-то текст на киррилице'.split(r));
```

**UPD2** с регистронезависимым разделением

```js
var separator = 'тЕк';
var r = new RegExp('('+separator+')',"i");
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify('какой-то текст на киррилице, Текст'.split(r));
```

Comment: проблема в том, что я знаю про регулярные выражения и про то что если использовать скобки то разделитель попадет в результирующий массив, но как сделать динамическое изменение этой регулярки??

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Можно еще вопрос? Как сделать это выражение регистронезависимым? Т.е. разделитель может быть 'Тек',  'тек' и т.д.

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, вторым параметром в конструкторе можно устанавливать флаги, в данном случае нужен флаг `"i"` - ignorecase. Обновил ответ

Comment: Еще раз спасибо)

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, пожалуйста :-)

Comment: Этот ответ попался мне в очереди проверок как аудит. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, как проверка? :)

Comment: @Grundy прошёл, конечно. )

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/50706

Comment: @NickVolynkin :-D low quality